# Correctness of networkx line digraph construction

Tags: networkx

The following Python code:

```
import networkx as nx
g = nx.DiGraph()
g.add_nodes_from([0, 1])
g.add_edges_from([(0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1)])
nx.write_dot(g, 'g.dot')
gl = nx.line_graph(g)
nx.write_dot(gl, 'gl.dot')
```

creates the following dot format graphs:

--- g.dot ---

```
digraph  {
    0 -> 0;
    0 -> 1;
    1 -> 0;
    1 -> 1;
}
```

---

--- gl.dot ---

```
strict digraph  {
    "(0, 1)" -> "(1, 1)";
    "(1, 0)" -> "(0, 0)";
    "(0, 0)" -> "(0, 1)";
    "(1, 1)" -> "(1, 0)";
}
```

---

Should the edges:

```
"(1, 0)" -> "(0, 1)";
"(0, 1)" -> "(1, 0)";
"(0, 0)" -> "(1, 1)";
"(1, 1)" -> "(0, 0)";
```

be in the line graph construction?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_graph#Line_digraph

Comment: I'm not sure, but what about "(1, 1)" -> "(1, 1)" and "(0, 0)" -> "(0, 0)"?

Comment: From Wikipedia: "Two vertices representing directed edges from u to v and from w to x in G are connected by an edge from uv to wx in the line digraph when v = w". It seems like NetworkX is operating under the condition that `u != x`. I don't know if this is correct or not.

Comment: I added the other edges that should also be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nx.line_graph` creates a strict DiGraph. Strict means there are no loops and no repeated edges. `"(0, 1)" -> "(1, 0)"` is a loop, so it is not included. In other words, "Two vertices representing directed edges from u to v and from w to x in G are connected by an edge from uv to wx in the **strict** line digraph when v = w **and u != x**". (Quote from Wikipedia - my insertions are bold).

Comment: The clue for me should have been in the strict keyword appearing in the dot file! I'm not sure whether this is a bug or a feature... but thanks for the pointers!

Comment: I'm not sure either. The docstring doesn't say anything about the result being strict. My only clue was the .dot file, too.

Answer (score 0):

The NetworkX line digraph code doesn't add isolates for self-loops nor does it allow creation of a self-loop in the line graph (loop of length 2 in original graph).

This may be a bug or a feature.  If someone could point me to the definition of the line graph for these cases maybe we can at least clarify the documentation or update the code.

Note that the dot file keyword "strict" in this case is basically true but just a happy coincidence that the code that writes dot files checks for self loops and multi-edges and uses "strict" if it doesn't find any.

Meantime here is a way to generate a directed line graph allowing both kinds of loops:

```
import networkx as nx
def directed_line_graph(G):
    L = nx.DiGraph()
    for u, adj in G.adjacency_iter():
        for v in adj:
            L.add_node((u,v))  # add self loops and single edges as nodes
            for w in G[v]: # neighbors of v
                if not (u == v and v == w):
                    L.add_edge((u,v),(v,w))
    return L

g = nx.DiGraph()
g.add_edges_from([(0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1)])
gl = directed_line_graph(g)
for e in gl.edges():
    print e
# ((0, 1), (1, 0))
# ((0, 1), (1, 1))
# ((1, 0), (0, 1))
# ((1, 0), (0, 0))
# ((0, 0), (0, 1))
# ((1, 1), (1, 0))
```

Comment: I believe that there should be 8 edges, i.e. including `((0, 0), (0, 0))` and `((1, 1), (1, 1))`. If the line, `if not (u == v and v == w):` is removed from your code above then the desired graph should be obtained I think.

Comment: Sure that is true.  I'm not sure what the standard definition is for directed line graph and if it includes those self-loop type edges or not.  It seemed reasonable to me that you shouldn't "re-use" a single edge to make a path of length two...

Comment: In the context of [de Bruijn graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_graph) the _line graph_ construction is understood to include the self loops. I think this agrees with the definition of [line digraph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_graph#Line_digraph) linked to in the question.

Comment: I see how it works for de Brujin graphs.  I opened an issue https://github.com/networkx/networkx/issues/937 to address this.